# Flashlight without FLASH_MODE_TORCH

Tags: android

Is there any options for turning the flash light on for undefined time when the phone isnt supporting the FLASH_MODE_TORCH in Camera.Parameters ?

I know it is possible becouse there are many of apps working on my phone (Samsung Galaxy ACE) but I dont find the answer yet.

I just came to:

```
Camera camera = Camera.open();
Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON) //because FLASH_MODE_TORCH isnt supported
camera.setParameters(params);
camera.startPreview();
camera.autoFocus(new AutoFocusCallback(){
public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera){
camera.autoFocus(this);
}
});
```

but this is working with little delay like 1/10 of second.

anybody ?

Answer (score 0):

May be delay comes from `autofocus`. Did you tried to set `focus` to infinity ?

```
params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_INFINITY);
```

Comment: Yes, delay comes becouse its autoFocusCallback so when the Focus is done it call onAutoFocus and theres the delay, I try to set FOCUS_MODE_INFINITY but only supported by my phone is AUTO and MACRO. I even try to change focus mode while is autofocus working but without success. I figure out that one app that works Tiny Flashlight working similiar. It start autofocusing but autofocus is going to sleep or something while LED is lightning and when its shutting down it just wake the thread or what and cancelAutoFocus. But i dont figure out how to sleep that thread.

Answer (score 0):

Set this code when Activity onCreat()

```
Camera camera = Camera.open();
Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();

private void TurnOn(){
   params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON) //because FLASH_MODE_TORCH isnt supported
   camera.setParameters(params);
   camera.startPreview();
}
```